# Native feature for Joomla Multisite 1.7

Tags: joomla, wordpress

Is there a native feature for Multisite in joomla 1.7?

and if not, can you reccomend me a extension for convert Joomla to Multisite?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*If you are looking for a Free/OpenSource tool:*

Someone wrote something for Google Summer of Code 2009 that adds multisite ability to Joomla 1.6 but it's not finished yet. Here is a [link](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2350441) to it's topic.

Later, someone else modified Joomla Multisite extension and made it availave for [download](http://cyberwizzard.nl/site/downloads/view.download/7/11.html). I've tested this component and it works with 1.7 like a charm.

*If you have no problem to pay:*

Without doubt, JMS is the best tool to make Joomla Multisite. take a look at [here](http://www.jms2win.com/).

**Note** that if you are a developer, check Nooku Framework (Based on Joomla 1.5 CMS). It has Multisite tools out of the box; but unfortunately Nooku is under development and is not stable for production usage.